# How does the LPtoDP function work?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a book about programming under Windows, and the author uses a function called LPtoDP ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca9sb0yt(VS.80).aspx)).

But I can't see the difference between code that uses this function and code that doesn't.

I use this function in this way, which seems to me to be a proper way.

```
POINT po;
po.x = -50;
po.y = 100;
pDC->LPtoDP(&po);
pDC->LineTo(po);
```

PS: First question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference becomes apparent when there is mapping mode set.

For example, as a result of viewport (scroll). Read about mapping modes here: http://wvware.sourceforge.net/caolan/mapmode.html